# php process eating CPU since October

Tags: php, cpu-usage

Just noticed that my server CPU is being eaten by php at a regular rate of 50-60%. Worse, this is happening since last October but I can't really remember what I did then to cause. The CPU graph for October looks like:

[image: CPU Usage in October of server]

Now, I don't want to go ahead and kill php as I might stop some important service but would like to find the culprit. What's the best way to go about this? I certainly don't think it's a webpage since my webserver gets very few hits.

Comment: How about investigating. For example, find the process that's eating the CPU and see what it's doing, what files it has open, and so on.

Comment: Good tip. :) It seems the problem is cacti.